# SQL join table and limiting condition matching result

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table of rates and transactions from which I want to find out conversion rate based on the latest updated currency rate (related to transaction timestamp)

```
Table - rates
('2018-04-01 00:00:00', 'EUR', 'RUB', '1.71'),
('2018-04-01 01:00:05', 'EUR', 'RUB', '1.82'),
('2018-04-01 00:00:00', 'USD', 'RUB', '0.71'),
('2018-04-01 00:00:05', 'USD', 'RUB', '0.82'),
('2018-04-01 00:01:00', 'USD', 'RUB', '0.92'),
('2018-04-01 01:02:00', 'USD', 'RUB', '0.62'),

Table - transactions
('2018-04-01 00:00:00', 1, 'EUR', 2.45),
('2018-04-01 01:00:00', 1, 'EUR', 8.45),
('2018-04-01 01:30:00', 1, 'USD', 3.5),
```

My attempt to limit those additional data

```
select * from transactions tr1 
left outer join rates ex1 
             on tr1.ts >= ex1.ts 
                and tr1.currency = ex1.from_currency;
```

The result I'm getting contains all of the exchange rate update that has happened previously 
2

```
2018-04-01 00:00:00 1   EUR 2.45    2018-04-01 00:00:00 EUR RUB 1.71 (correct)
2018-04-01 01:00:00 1   EUR 8.45    2018-04-01 00:00:00 EUR RUB 1.71 (correct)
2018-04-01 01:30:00 1   USD 3.5     2018-04-01 01:02:00 USD RUB 0.62 (only this should remain)
2018-04-01 01:30:00 1   USD 3.5     2018-04-01 00:01:00 USD RUB 0.92
2018-04-01 01:30:00 1   USD 3.5     2018-04-01 00:00:05 USD RUB 0.82
2018-04-01 01:30:00 1   USD 3.5     2018-04-01 00:00:00 USD RUB 0.71
```

I tried to define my own statement (my previous query):

```
where ex1.ts = (select max(ex2.ts) from rates ex2 
                where ex2.from_currency=ex1.from_currency 
                      and ex2.to_currency=ex1.from_currency);
```

But that doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has the very handy `distinct on` for getting one row per group.  This should do what you want:

```
select t.*, r.*
from transactions t left join
     (select distinct on (from_currency, to_currency) r.*
      from rates r
      order by from_currency, to_currency, ts desc
     ) r
     on r.from_currency = t.currency and
        r.to_currency = 'RUB';
```

EDIT:

If you want the latest date for each transaction, then use a lateral join:

```
select t.*, r.*
from transactions t left join lateral
     (select r.*
      from rates r
      where r.from_currency = t.currency and
            r.ts <= t.ts
      order by r.ts desc
      limit 1
     ) r
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: Wondering how does this query handles the requirement that only those exchange rates should come which has been recorded on or before the transaction time. If I understand correctly, this query will always get the latest exchange rate for every currency, irrespective of the transaction time

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya . . . Your reading of the question makes more sense.  I focused on the "latest updated currency rate".  I added what should be the best solution, which is a lateral join.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using Window/Analytic functions. In the partition, we order by `ex1.ts` in descending order, so that we get the rate closest to the transaction timestamp `ts`. `tr1.ts >= ex.ts` condition in the Join ensures that we are only getting the exchange rates on or before the transaction time.

```
select dt.* 
from 
(
select tr1.*, ex1.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by ex1.from_currency order by ex1.ts desc) as rn
from transactions tr1 
left outer join exchange_rates ex1 
             on tr1.ts >= ex1.ts 
                and tr1.currency = ex1.from_currency
) as dt 
where dt.rn = 1
```